# Create a calculated column based on evaluating whether some of several columns are true?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query creating a calculated column based on evaluating whether several existing columns are true.

For example, if I wanted the output of the column to be 'No' if any 3 or more of 7 columns happen to be null, 'Maybe' if any 2 of them happens to be null, and "Yes" if any one of them happens to be null. A case statement seems like it would require each possible combination of columns to be enumerated.

I looked into creating a local variable, and then setting/redefining it within a select statement, but I can't find anything about what syntax can do this (assuming it's possible). What is the way to do this?

Comment: If it wasn't a computed column, just a `select`, then a subquery would work `(select case when count(val) >= 3 then 'No' ... from (values(col1),(col2)...) v(val))`

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Please show some sample data, expected results and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but here's an option:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ADD CalculatedColumn AS (
 CASE (CASE WHEN col_a IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN col_b IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ...)
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Maybe'
  ELSE 'No' --3 or more
 END
);
```

You could also add a case for 0, however you wanted to handle that.

Comment: Ok, I see calculating using nested case statements. This is quite a lot better than defining each combination of variables, thank you. SQL seems a confusing in how limited select and case syntax is...

Answer (score 0):

From a query perspective, you can try something like the following:

```
-- Create a mock-up table.
DECLARE @Data table (
    col1 varchar(10),
    col2 varchar(10),
    col3 varchar(10),
    col4 varchar(10),
    col5 varchar(10),
    col6 varchar(10),
    col7 varchar(10),
    id int IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )
);

-- Insert some mock data.
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', NULL, NULL ),
    ( 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', NULL );

-- Query data and return Yes, No, Maybe based on the number of null columns.
;WITH col_data AS (
    SELECT
        id,
          CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col6 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN col7 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        AS null_sum
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT
    id,
    null_sum,
    CASE
        WHEN null_sum <= 1 THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN null_sum <= 2 THEN 'Maybe'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS msg
FROM col_data;
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | null_sum |  msg  |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        3 | No    |
|  2 |        2 | Maybe |
|  3 |        1 | Yes   |
+----+----------+-------+
```